# When worldbuilding, which aspect do you start with?

Tags: society, gods

> I personally started with the Pantheon of the Gods and Goddesses. That way, I can explain my world.

Comment: This sort of "discussion generation" question isn't really a good fit for the stack exchange system (although feel free to pop into the chat once you have 20 reputation and people can discuss as much as they like there!). There would need to be rather more structure to define what makes a good answer and how they should be evaluated before this could be opened.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding, Gafgarion, regrettably your question is a better fit for WB SE's chat rather than the general question stream. Please take time to see the sort of questions & the topics that are asked here. When gain sufficient reputation (20 points) you will be able to access chat & you can take it there.

Comment: The URL for WB SE's chat, the Factory Floor, is https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor This is the best venue for wide ranging, open ended topics.

Comment: @TimB While I am in full agreement about this question being discussion generation best suited to the Factory Floor, I am in a quandary because the reason for putting it on hold is nonsense. You and I have specific expertise in the facts of how we begin building our worlds. Surely references can be found about author's practices in the art of worldbuilding. Obviously there will not be one true answer (thus better for chat), one thing they won't be is primarily opinion-based. No more than usually. I agree it should be on hold, I doubt the reason.

Comment: @a4android There are plenty of such references! Every geopoet with a blog has got specific expertise regarding where she herself started and also opinions where one in general might should start. I don't have a blog, but I still have specific expertise & opinions. I concur that this part of the forum is not the best place for this kind of question. I also concur that we who are experienced geopoets should feel free to broach topics like this at the Factory Floor (which I have yet to find (thanks for the link!)).

Comment: @a4android There are hundreds of potential places to start and no way to say which would be best for the person asking the question or anyone interested in the answer - it's all down to the asker's opinion. There is also no way to know which answer might be better than any others - it's all down to the voters opinion. Without objective criteria it's opinion based.

Comment: @TimBSorry, Diamond Tim, you've missed my point. The criteria as stated for primary opinion based fail in this case. if the criteria fail, then the reason for putting on hold itself fails. It's that simple. This rationale about knowing which answer is better than any others is hot air. It can be based on the OP's acceptance; after all, who else chooses. This seems to be something that while it sounds credible. It can be believed by people who haven't had much contact with reality where there are multitudes of situations where there is no one good answer.

Comment: I guess I didn't know that this site was not about opinions. I rather hear from the public about their opinions, hence I'm here. Or was here. I don't believe that the answer would have to be fact based. I will ask it somewhere else then. Thank you,  @Sasha for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The themes of the story.

I think about what kind of story I want to tell and what kind of character will exist in the world.

I usually like to start with the characters in the Earth and then see what changes will facilitate the story and what these elements mean to the story as a whole.